# How do I upload a files to common Google Drive using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

I want know how we user common google drive for file upload from my flutter app?

I tried more ways and those are not sutible for my requirment

Comment: Can you elaborate more with your requirements

Comment: What exactly is **user common google drive**?

Answer (score 1):

### Process

1. Create GCP Project and Enable Drive API and generate credentials
2. Either directly use https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/about-sdk or use this package https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis